# Redis cannot serialize/deserialize inner Map objects

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using redis repository over spring. In the repository, redis is not deserializing  the data structure explained below.

```
class A {
  String id;
  Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> someData;
}
```

It gives this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set
> property final float java.util.HashMap.loadFactor!

Redis, as default, looks for no-args constructor. If missing, it uses all-args constructor. If no one is there, it uses custom constructor. But I do not have. control over Map so can you help me to resolve this problem? I have not instantiated any converters separately. Default config is there.

Thx